# How to get line strings with special word start and end?

Tags: linux, shell, cat

Here is the file strings.xml which includeing 3 sentences:

1.string name="schedulelist_nofiles">Não existe agenda de registro! Por favor,

here is missing line tecla “Add” (Adicionar) para adicionar uma. string

2.You should skip this line!

3.string name="Programme_name">GUIA DE PROGRAMA string

I use cat command 'cat strings.xml | grep "string name=" but it only get below lines:

string name="schedulelist_nofiles">Não existe agenda de registro! Por favor,

string name="Programme_name">GUIA DE PROGRAMA string

I want to get the complete line like this , just like sentence 3, start with 'string name' and end with "string".
What can I do for this?

Comment: you can try `sed '/first words/,/last words/ !d'` to select lines that match this pattern be careful to choose the rigth pattern to not select paragraph :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below sed oneliner can be used to achieve the same. Tested it worked fine

First method1

```
sed -n '/^string name.*string$/p'  filename
```

## In method1 It will searches for line beginning with "string name" and ends with "string"

Method 2

```
sed -n '/^string name/p' filename | sed -n '/string$/p'
```

## In method2 First it will searches for line beginning with "string name" and then it searches for line ending with string

Output

```
string name="Programme_name">GUIA DE PROGRAMA string
```

Answer (score 0):

With `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -Mo '(?s)\bstring name=.*?\bstring\b' < file.xml
```

- `-M`: multi-line mode where pcregrep pulls more lines from the input as needed to satisfy the regex
- `-o`: print the portion that matches the regexp like in GNU `grep` (you can omit it or replace with `-x` if the regex matches full lines.
- `(?s)`: activate the `s` flag that causes `.` to also match on newline
- `.*?`: non-greedy version of `.*`: any number of characters, as few as possible.
- `\b`: word boundary.

If you don't have `pcregrep`, you can do the same with `perl` with something like:

```
perl -l -0777 -ne 'print for /\bstring name=.*?\bstring\b/gs' < file.xml
```

Though that means loading the whole file in memory.

Comment: I use the Linux server to scripting, and I don't have root permission, so the command pcregrep can not be installed, other command can replace it?

Comment: Thanks very much. If above 3 scentens I just want to get the first one, how can I do? I mean only need to capture the string ID 'schedulelist_nofiles' sentence, don't includeing the last scentens, how can I filter it? Because it is also including keys words 'string name= ... string'.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`, assuming those `string name= ... string` take up full lines and that all `string name=`s are terminated by a `string`:

```
sed '
  /^string name=/!d
  :1
  / string$/!{
    N
    b1
  }' < strings.xml
```